# WHERE clause with multiples conditions with values from the SELECT

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to edit an old Access form.

When a person enters information into a form field, a number associated to a name is found through a SQL SELECT statement.

```
"SELECT * FROM TPro WHERE Name = " & Chr(34) & cboPro.Value & Chr(34)
```

The TPro Table looks like this:

```
ID          Name               QtyMin        QtyMax     Percent
-------- ---------------- --------------- ----------- ----------
001     |   2x4 plank    |       0       |    500    |    10    
002     |   6x8 plank    |       0       |    500    |    5 
003     |   6x8 plank    |      501      |   2000    |    10 
004     |   6x8 plank    |      2001     |   99999   |    15
005     |   10x8 plank   |       0       |    500    |    5
```

For this example let's say the Name found is "**6x8 plank**" and the number is **600**. The number is stored in a variable called **qtyCmd**

Now I need to select which of the 3 "6x8 plank" rows is the correct one, I need to find the one that 600 is BETWEEN qtyMin and qtyMax so I know which percentage is the correct one to apply (in this case it would be 10).

I thought I could get all this through the original SELECT statement like that, but I get an error that it's missing something.

```
"SELECT * FROM TPro WHERE Name = " & Chr(34) & cboPro.Value & Chr(34) AND (qtyCmd >= QtyMin & qtyCmd <= QtyMax)
```

Would something like this allow me to find the correct row? or would I need something more complex in order to do this?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my lacking English.

Comment: Visual Basic still tells me that I have Compilation Error regarding syntax. I'll double check about what i'm using... thanks for the help

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more what `qtyCmd` is... I do not see it defined anywhere. I see where you talk about it, but that does not explain it at all. If it's not a field in your table, then you cannot use it in your query. Is it some kind of control maybe?

Comment: Post your code - not selected strings

Comment: use bind parameters "Select * From Tpro where Name = @Name"  cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", whatever your name logic is)

Comment: As @BryanDellinger said, take care for `SQL Injection`

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
"SELECT * FROM TPro WHERE Name = '" & Me.cboPro & "' AND " & qtyCmd & " BETWEEN QtyMin AND QtyMax"
```

I presume you are setting a recordset object with that SQL. However, if all you want is a single value, could just use DLookup() domain aggregate function.

```
x = DLookup("[Percent]", "TPro", "[Name] = '" & Me.cboPro & "' AND " & qtyCmd & " BETWEEN QtyMin AND QtyMax")
```

And then another approach is a combobox that shows all those TPro fields in dropdown and user selects correct item then the Percent is available by reference to combobox column. But perhaps it is demanding too much of users to evaluate which range the qtyCmd value falls into.

Regardless of approach, only the TPro ID should be saved into data - unless there is possibility Percent values in TPro could be changed in future.